# ASP.NET DropdownList Always insert the first item

Tags: asp.net

I have dropdownlist on my website. When I select the any item to insert the database but it does not insert selected item always insert the first item inside the dropdown list. Please Help How can I solve that problem?

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
    GetCategory();
   }
}


void GetCategory()
{
    dlCategory.DataSource = Data.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM tblCategory");
    dlCategory.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
    dlCategory.DataValueField = "ID"; 
    dlCategory.DataBind();
    dlCategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    dlCategory.SelectedIndex = dlCategory.Items.IndexOf(dlCategory.Items.FindByText("--Select--"));
}

SqlConnection baglanti = Data.baglan();
SqlCommand tr = new SqlCommand("Insert tblProduct (CategoryID) values(@CategoryID)", baglanti);

tr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", dlCategory.SelectedValue);
tr.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The  execute code is not in a function why ?? Please make effort to indent code, this does not make sense

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit blurry regarding the code, so correct me if I misunderstood, but I presume you want to do the following in WebForms:

- Simply show all available categories that can be assigned to a
  product
- When the user selects the category and hits submit, it will be inserted to the DB assegnied to it

It is not quite elegant, but I would put something like this:

```
    private SqlConnection _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _sqlConnection.ConnectionString = @".." //Assign whatever your ConnectionString is in Data.baglan();
        _sqlConnection.Open();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetCategory();
        }
        else
        {
            //Define your insert something like this, and I would put this into the submit Button_Click event:
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dlCategory.SelectedValue) && dlCategory.SelectedValue != "0")
            {
                SqlCommand tr = new SqlCommand("Insert tblProduct (CategoryID) values (@CategoryID)", _sqlConnection);
                tr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", dlCategory.SelectedValue);
                tr.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO: Handle wrong selection, eg display an error message..
            }
        }
    }

    void GetCategory()
    {
        dlCategory.DataSource = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblCategory", _sqlConnection).ExecuteReader();
        dlCategory.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
        dlCategory.DataValueField = "ID";
        dlCategory.DataBind();
        dlCategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        dlCategory.SelectedIndex = dlCategory.Items.IndexOf(dlCategory.Items.FindByText("--Select--"));
    }
```